# T1 spin-lattice relaxation times, deviation from exponential relationship

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, magnetism, spin

For longitudinal relaxation, one would think that the magnetic moment obeys this simple relationship

$$M_z = M_0\left[1 - 2\exp\left(\frac{-t}{T_1}\right)\right].$$

However there is always a point of inflection when magnetisation is zero. Does anyone knows why?

edit: I deleted the image and added some from my own experiment for mineral oil.

In this scenario, the sample is placed under a large longitudinal z-magnetic field. To measure T1, a 180 degree pulse is applied to flip Mz, then a 90 degree pulse after time t. Mo is the equilibrium longitudinal magnetic moment.

I don't think this is due to the mixture of compounds, because it is observed in all samples I tried e.g glycerine, Fe(NO3)3.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please cite the source of the image and/or data and define the variables in the equation to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Possibly the data refers to a mixture of compounds whose chemical shift  are overlapping. Look for data on a known pure compound for comparison.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please? I don't see any inflection point there -- your graph is quite clearly concave -- and I don't think I've ever seen an inflection point in the inversion-recovery experiments I've done before ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goHwt.png)). Btw, your equation is missing a minus sign inside the exponential.

Comment: The inflection point is quite slight, if you look at the ln(Mz) against time plot, there is a  small difference between the gradient below ~0.02s and after. It occurs when the sign of the Mz flips. Maybe because your data started at positive Mz ? @orthocresol (also added a -ve sign)

Comment: No, it doesn't start at positive Mz. I don't have an explanation for what you're seeing, unfortunately; I just can't say I've seen it before myself.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Could you post the equation you are using to generate the log plot, because you must be subtracting a constant before taking the logarithm. Magnetization damping can be an issue and non-exponential behavior is certainly not uncommon for many reasons, instrumental not being the least. But this inflection is as you point out very faint and I cannot think of an explanation.

Comment: Also, what kind of setup are you using, lowfield with no spectral resolution or high field, with spectral resolution and picking selected spectral regions?